# Bundling a Realm with an App section

Tags: swift, cocoa, realm

I am trying to bundle a realm file with my app. I followed steps 1-5, but I am not clear on step 6. It says to copy the file back to the document folder, especially if it will be edited by the users.

Assuming, the copy statement goes inside the AppDelegate (similar to how it is done in the sample migration code), and the file is copied, what will happen the next time the app is launched? will it copy the file again, and overwrite it? Am I missing something?

Do I need to run it once before I ship the app, and then remove the code from the app delegate?

EDIT: this question is regarding realm-swift

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you bundle Realm file with your app it will be stored inside your app's bundle in Resources directory which is not writeable (because of the code signing). So if you want your users be able to change this data you have to copy this file to some directory with write access. Application’s Documents directory seems to be a good choice and it's also a default directory for default `Realm.Configuration`.

If it's an initial data for your app and you don't want to overwrite it each time your app launches, you can simply check if destination file exists and not copy your initial database in this case.

You can do it like this:

```
let initialURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("initial", withExtension: "realm")!
let defaultURL = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!

if (!defaultURL.checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError(nil)) {
    do {
        try NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtURL(initialURL, toURL: defaultURL)
    } catch {
        // Handle error here
    }
 }


 let realm = try! Realm()
```

Comment: @Dimtry thank you. one more quick question - I know that realm uses the default.realm by default, however, in case my initial db file name is different, do I need to created a special realm configuration? I intend to keep the initial realm file as 'default.realm' so will it be safe to just overwrite it?

Comment: You can specify the name of realm file also while creating `Realm`, see https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#realms for more info. And yes, you can just overwrite your "default" realm with the initial one, it doesn't matter how they are named actually.

Comment: sadly the solution above did not work for me. The condition !defaultURL.checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError(nil) is always false because after my app launched, realm already been initialized by the view controllers and a new default.realm file has been created. The problem is, the view controllers fetch data using realm and if I centralized the realm initialization, then the app will break. I ended up cheating and checking if my database is empty, and if it is, I seed it, otherwise, I don't.

Comment: You should check if default Realm exists before you creating it of course, but checking if it's empty might be also a solution. It depends on your app.

Comment: I was actually thinking about embedding your code in a lazy property so when the realm instance is first created, I will check if a realm file exists, which shouldn't be, and do the copy.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the above answer. Looks like currently the correct version of checking if realm file exists is: defaultURL.checkResourceIsReachable()